# Finding if a group of polynom field is a vector space

Tags: vector-spaces

we have the following group $$P = \{p(x) \in \mathbb{R}^4[x] | p (x) = p (1-x)\} $$

and I need to find out if this is group is vector space or not.
and I am not even sure what could $P$ contain.

I think that the only possibility of a $p(x)$ to exist in $P$ is if both $p(x)$ and $p(x-1)$ will return 0.
am I right?

also I thought that in order to rule out the possibility of this group be a vector space. I could prove that it does not have a identity element(neutral), but I am not sure how to start proving it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To give you a better feel: Some examples of elements of $P$ are $p(x)=42$, $p(x)=-x^2+x+666$, $p(x)=x^4-2x^3+x^2$, $p(x)=x^4-2x^3+x$.

In order to show that $P$ is a vector space, show that the axioms hold. In fact, it shoul dturn out to be a *subspace* of $\mathbb R^4[x]$, so you could simply apply some *subspace criterion* that you should have avaliable.

Comment: first, thank you for your answer! since I could only check the subspace axioms (closure on addition and multiplication, and identity element). I was trying to prove the Closure on addition and got stuck $x,y \in P$ and $x+y = ?$ not sure how I could prove those axioms with a Polynom.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: This is similar to the problem of determining the set
$$\{ p(x) \in \mathbb{R}_4[x] \ | \ p(x) = p(-x)\}$$
(polynomials of degree at most $4$). This set is formed of polynomials of form
$$p(x) = q(x^2)$$ where $q$ is a polynomial of degree at most $2$.

So with your problem, it will be the set of polynomials of form
$$p(x) = q(x(1-x))$$ where $q$ is a polynomial of degree at most $2$.

Check the axioms for a vector space. Yes, it is.